# submit sbatch jobs in loop

Tags: bash, shell, slurm, sbatch

I have a txt file (say jobs.txt) that has several lines like:

"sbatch -w node00x script.sh 1"
"sbatch -w node00z script.sh 10"
.
. 
etc

I wonder if it is possible to create an executable bash file like the following

#!/bin/bash

while read -r line;
do **submit the job by line**; 
done < jobs.txt;

that I can just execute and which will run the jobs in respective nodes. I have very limited knowledge in this area. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: why not `. jobs.txt` or `source jobs.txt` ?

Comment: Is there a strong reason why you specify manually the compute nodes on which you want to run each job? Also I suspect your use case really fits a job array ; if that's the case, you could greatly simplify your whole process.

Comment: @damienfrancois- Yes. I need very specific nodes. My script.sh has job-array set up for any particular node which will be queued. You are right though. I also think, even this can be achieved by carefully creating job-array setup. But I am no expert in this.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to do eval command:

```
eval $line
```

Comment: this worked! The only thing I had to do is to remove the quotes.

Comment: Use tr to remove the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do in those cases is:

```
./jobs.txt
```

If you have set the execution permissions for that file (as its extension suggests), give them to it:

```
chmod u+x jobs.txt
```

And if it is necessary, I would add to the head of the *jobs.txt*:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

And if you want to remove any confusion with the file name, rename it:

```
mv jobs.txt jobs.sh
```

Now, you have a workload ready to be submitted!

Comment: thanks for the nice solution!  Basically it avoided creating an extra launcher script.